# Calculate pairwise Jaccard index between character vectors in a list

Tags: r

I have character vectors in the following format

```
char1 <- c(“Hello”, “was”, “this”, “is”, “that”, “Boston”, “San”, “Francisco”)
char2 <- c(“John”, “was”, “they”, “is”, “Hello”, “Boston”, “San”, “Diego”)
char3 <- c(“John”, “very”, “happens”, “is”, “Hello”, “has”, “San”, “Diego”)

list <- list(char1, char2, char3)
```

However, I have around 500 of these, each of length 100,000.

How can I calculate the pairwise Jaccard index (similarity measure) of all vectors in this list and output it as a data frame (NA for comparing the same character vector)? What would be the most efficient way of doing so?

Thanks!

Comment: look at `stringdist::stringdist`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following to obtain all the pairwise distances with `union` and `intersect` in `dplyr`

```
dist <- unlist(lapply(combn(list, 2, simplify = FALSE), function(x) {
  length(intersect(x[[1]], x[[2]]))/length(union(x[[1]], x[[2]])) }))

dist
[1] 0.4545455 0.2307692 0.4545455
```

To see which pairs are associated with which values you could add the indices:

```
cbind(t(combn(3,2)), dist)

              dist
[1,] 1 2 0.4545455
[2,] 1 3 0.2307692
[3,] 2 3 0.4545455
```